# Android programming - how to retrieve data specific to a key value from sqlite database in multiple listviews

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-sqlite

I'm developing an app and have created an sqlite database, a custom adapter to help display it in a listview, an activity to get the input to populate the database and an activity with viewpager to swipe across listviews. 
What i want to do is have seven pages, one for each day of the week and to display the entire database spread out on their corresponding days. The fields in the database are lesson, day, start time, end time and location.
Currently what i have is an app that displays all the data to one page and i can't figure out how to display the data between more pages based on the 'Day' field. 
Any advice or tutorial links would be much appreciated! thanks.

Here is some code:

```
/*main class with viewpager there is an action bar with an action item to
the input activity */

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ScheduleActivity extends Activity {

private Context mContext;

DBSchedule db = new DBSchedule(this);
private ScheduleAdapter scheduleAdapter;
private static final int ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
Cursor c;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mContext = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);

        ListView listview1 = new ListView(mContext);
        ListView listview2 = new ListView(mContext);
        ListView listview3 = new ListView(mContext);

        Vector<View> pages = new Vector<View>();

        pages.add(listview1);
        pages.add(listview2);
        pages.add(listview3);

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        PageAdapter adapter = new PageAdapter(mContext,pages);
        vp.setAdapter(adapter);


        db.open();

        scheduleAdapter = new ScheduleAdapter(ScheduleActivity.this, db.getAllEntries(),CursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION );
        listview1.setAdapter(scheduleAdapter);      

        db.close();

        listview2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,new String[]{"A2","B2","C2","D2"}));
        listview3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,new String[]{"A3","B3","C3","D3"}));

    }
```

Custom page adapter

```
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Vector;

    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class PageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

 private Context mContext;
 private Vector<View> pages;

 public PageAdapter(Context context, Vector<View> pages) {
  this.mContext=context;
  this.pages=pages;
 }

 @Override
 public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
  View page = pages.get(position);
  container.addView(page);
  return page;
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  return pages.size();
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
  return view.equals(object);
 }

 @Override
 public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
  container.removeView((View) object);
 }
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post only the **relevant** code.

Comment: Solved this by creating queryies with WHERE clauses in the database class that retrieves data based on the Value specified and then calling them in the appropriate listviews